# LinkedIn Profile Image missing on Authentication from App

Tags: linkedin-api

I use `REST API` to share articles/posts on LinkedIn Timeline and Company pages. To do so, I authorize my LI profile with the APP for accessing the profile info.  As a result, could view the profile/image of a user in the APP. Everything worked fine until, for some time now, aren't able to view the user profile image from the APP. Now, it looks like:

[image]

Previous image URL starts with(accessible): `https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_`
Current image URL starts with(could not access): `https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/`

On accessing the image in the browser, [image]

Help me understand what has changed with LI. Thanks.

Comment: Updating login servers resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you injecting the URL in same way that's escaping it? The URL recently changed and has some characters that templating engines such as Handlebars will mistakenly escape.

If you inject the URL without escaping it, it should work just fine.

Comment: we dont escape the url. But couldn't access.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this documentation. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/media-migration,

The problem which I was facing was the image loaded sometimes, but after some days it would give above error.

`The new id will be dynamic and can change from time to time. We recommend retrieving at least once every 60 days to update your media-typed URN.`

In order to fix this, I save the image, the moment it is received on to personal storage(AWS S3).